# Magento event not caught by observer when fired via SOAP

Tags: magento, events, soap

Despite the multitude of 'my observer isn't triggered' questions on SO, this one has not yet been covered.

I have a **working** observer set up to catch the event checkout_submit_all_after. The problem is that this only works when I purchase an item via the frontend, and not when I trigger the event via a SOAP call to shopppingCartOrder. The order itself is successful, and I also am able to log the event from Mage.php's dispatchEvent.

Edit: To make this more clear: The event IS being generated and I can log it via Mage.php. The problem is that **the observer is not catching it only when SOAP is used to generate the event**.

As you will see from my config.xml below, I am using the Global scope, so the observer should be handling it in all cases (if my understanding is correct). Is there something else I need to do to get my observer to fire when i call SOAP? Also, I tried this with various other events and still nothing triggered.

config.xml:

```
<config>

    <modules>
        <Company_Obsrv>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Company_Obsrv>
    </modules>

    <global>
       <models>
            <!--
                Unique identifier in the model's node.
                By convention, we put the module's name in lowercase.
            -->
            <company_obsrv>
            <!--path-->
                <class>Company_Obsrv_Model</class>
            </company_obsrv>

        </models>

        <events>
            <checkout_submit_all_after>
                <observers>
                    <company_obsrv>
                        <class>company_obsrv/observer</class>
                        <method>observeTest</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </company_obsrv>
                </observers>
            </checkout_submit_all_after>
        </events>
    </global>   

</config>
```

Observer.php:

```
class Company_Obsrv_Model_Observer
{

    public function observeTest(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
       Mage::log('CALLED!', null, 'newlog.log', true); 
    } 
}
```

Like I said, the observer works when I'm not using SOAP, so it can't be my function code or naming issues. Please help!

Comment: Which magento version,you have using???

Comment: I am on version 1.8.1.0, is this a known bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grrr! It was the damn CACHE. And I was sure I turned it off.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was also caught with by this silly newbie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If this particular event does not fire when an order is placed via SOAP, there are two solutions:

1. Listen for a more generalized event, such as `sales_order_place_after`. If you don't want this to fire from the admin area, you can move the events configuration out of the global node and into the frontend node.
2. Create a custom SOAP endpoint and fire a unique event yourself:

   `Mage::dispatchEvent('soap_order_place_after', array('order'=>$order));`

Comment: No, what I said was the event IS being generated (I am able to log it when it comes into Mage.php's dispatchEvent). I also tested other events and while the event fires, the **observer** does not catch it.

Comment: It would probably work with a custom SOAP endpoint but do I really have to go to the trouble of this? All I want to do is catch an event that I KNOW is being generated!

Comment: Can you provide the code for 'company_obsrv/observer'?

Comment: Added the code. It catches the event fine when the event is fired from the frontend, so I don't see how it could be this that is the problem.

Comment: Just so I understand, with the code you have in your question right now, what happens when an order is placed via frontend, and what happens what an order is placed via SOAP?

Comment: When an order is placed via frontend: event is logged via the Mage::Log which I placed in Mage.php, also another log is made by the observer.

When an order is placed via SOAP, the event is logged from Mage.php, but not the observer.

Nothing else is done yet, this is just placeholder code until I can get the thing to actually call.